# Возможно ли построить на Java конструктор выборки значения из строки?

Tags: java, android

Клиент на Адроид. Сервера есть разные у всех свой апи.
Получаю ответ от сервера в виде строки со своей иерархией или json.

Нужно придумать такой себе конструктор выборки из строки что бы пользователь мог сам выбирать нужное значение.

В итоге выборка может получиться

```
X=text.split(";",3).split(",",2).split(" ",1)
```

или

```
String line = line0.split("|",20);
int pos1 = line.indexOf("[");
int pos2 = line.indexOf("]");
String text = line.substring(pos1,pos2);
X=text.split(";",3);
```

Жалко в Java нельзя исполнять код из стрингов.

Городить выбор сочетаний split.substring.split не охота, может есть какое решение?

Comment: Можете привести пример текста? Вы можете сделать несколько конструкторов.

Comment: Если строка это всегда jason, то можно его распарсить и ходить по нему. Например пользователь ввел "foo.bar.baz" и мы берем у рута свойство foo, затем у получившегося объекта свойство bar и так далее. Наверно даже есть библиотеки для этого.

Comment: К джаве можно подключать скриптовые языки, например javascript.